# Replacement for obselete Infineon TLE52062GAUMA1 device?

Tags: motor, driver, h-bridge

I have an existing system that I wish to replace one of these Infineon TLE52062GAUMA1 motor drivers in. It's a H-bridge 40V/5A driver in a TO263 package. (https://ie.farnell.com/infineon/tle52062gauma1/motor-driver-h-bridge-to-263-7/dp/2480504)

It turns out that the device is obsolete and unavailable from Mouser, Digikey, RS etc. I might be able to get it from other suppliers like TME (I'm in Europe), but I have never dealt with them before and anyhow the part is only available until they run out, which is not helpful for the future. Ideally I'd like a pin-compatible and functional replacement that is readily available. I'd be grateful for any information on this. Infineon don't seem to have a replacement, but maybe there is another manufacturer with something close enough.

Comment: You would like to repair or make a new device?

Comment: Its a repair, I look after a lab with several of these systems, so would be nice to have a reliable source of spares rather than buy a load of obsolete parts just in case.

Comment: You  might need to use something else on its own module and load terminals and tap out the control signals.

Comment: I'm sure hoping to avoid that, but I accept it is possibly all I can do. There is not a lot of space in there, but it is doable.....